# Mod rewrite breaks using name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^member/([^/][0-9]*)$ profile.php?id=$1
```

and it works as it should what I am trying to do is instead of id I want to use name. so I changed my link accordingly and tried

```
RewriteRule ^member/([^/][0-9]*)$ profile.php?name=$1
```

and I get page cannot be found I am retrieving the name and ID together.

username may have characters in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^member/([^\/\?\#]+) profile.php?name=$1
```

This should do the trick.